# Prove that the degree of every irreducible representation divides $[ G : Z(G) ]$

Tags: representation-theory, divisibility, irreducible-representation

The question is essentially the title. We assume that $G$ is a finite group and the irrep is over $\mathbb C$. $Z(G)$ is the center of $G$.

The caveat is that I'm looking for an "elementary" proof. I've found [this](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Degree_of_irreducible_representation_divides_index_of_abelian_normal_subgroup) already, which is proving a more general theorem, which uses induced representations and isotypical representations.

My question whether it's possible to prove the result without using these tools, and using only "elementary" results from representation theory.

Comment: Um, in the linked page they already assume known your fact (called Fact $(7)$ there) and then prove the more general theorem, and when going to the page of Fact $(7)$ they do not provide a proof of it, so even your link does not give a proof of your desired result.

Comment: It's hard to know what you mean by "elementary" results from representation theory if induced representations don't make the cut.

Comment: Theorem $4$ of this page seemingly has a proof of the statement, if anyone would be willing to check the veracity of the proof and/or make it an answer: https://amathew.wordpress.com/2009/10/11/divisibility-theorems-for-group-representations/

Comment: @Stephen By elementary I mean stuff like the orthogonality relations, Schur's lemma and such.

Comment: @BrunoB Indeed, you're right. I only skimmed the page, sorry. In this case, I'm looking for *any* proof pretty much.

Comment: Theorem 3.12 in Isaac's book *Character theory of finite groups* is exactly what you want (doesn't use induced characters, does use orthogonality relations and some elementary algebraic number theory).